# Bootstrap/JQuery - Radio Button Group Event Functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

My goal is to run a function depending upon what radio button in a group is selected. Using other posts I was able to implement the bellow scripts. Here are the errors I am encountering: 
    1) The initial button that I declare to be checked by default does not call a function. If I remove the checked attribute from the button it functions as the others do. 
    2) Each button works only once. For example if I click button two, it fires the appropriate function. Then when button 3 is clicked, it too functions successfully. The problem is when I then try to go back to button 2. It will not fire a second time.

**JQUERY**

```
$("#btn-group-data :input").on("change",function () {
    switch (this.value) {
        case "radar":
            console.log(this.value); 
            //do stuff...
            break;
        case "watches":
            console.log(this.value);
            //do stuff... 
            break;
        case "warnings":
            console.log(this.value);
            //do stuff...
            break;
        case "temp":
            console.log(this.value); // points to the clicked input button
            //do stuff...
            break;
        case "precip":
            console.log(this.value); // points to the clicked input button
            //do stuff...
            break;
        case "snow":
            console.log(this.value); // points to the clicked input button
            //do stuff...
            break;
    }
});
```

**BUTTON-HTML**

```
<div id="map-container" class="container-fluid">
    <div id="map-div">
        <div id="btn-group-data" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-primary active">
                <input type="radio" name="radar" value="radar" id="radar" autocomplete="off" checked="" > Radar
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary ">
                <input type="radio" name="watches" value="watches" id="watches" autocomplete="off"> Watches
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
                <input type="radio" name="warnings" value="warnings" id="warnings" autocomplete="off"> Warnings
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
                <input type="radio" name="temp" value="temp" id="temp" autocomplete="off"> Temperature
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
                <input type="radio" name="precip" value="precip" id="precip" autocomplete="off"> Precipitation
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
                <input type="radio" name="snow" value="snow" id="snow" autocomplete="off"> Snow
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give the same name to all your inputs like this

```
<div id="map-div">
    <div id="btn-group-data" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-primary active">
            <input type="radio" name="radar" value="radar" id="radar" autocomplete="off" checked="" > Radar
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary ">
            <input type="radio" name="radar" value="watches" id="watches" autocomplete="off"> Watches
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="radio" name="radar" value="warnings" id="warnings" autocomplete="off"> Warnings
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="radio" name="radar" value="temp" id="temp" autocomplete="off"> Temperature
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="radio" name="radar" value="precip" id="precip" autocomplete="off"> Precipitation
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="radio" name="radar" value="snow" id="snow" autocomplete="off"> Snow
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works, Is there any documentation that explains why this  has to be set up in this way?

Comment: the inputs are all radio buttons and therefore require the same name - this is a basic HTML requirement - not related to the button group, Bootstrap or jQuery.